# CORS Javascript Server Side Vs Client Side

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, node.js, express

I am currently in the planning stages of a new app. And the API I want to use does not allow CORS with client side javascript. As a front end developer I would use a simple ajax request. Is it possible to do a request from server side javascript using express to bypass CORS? Or am I limited to using another language such as ruby to make the requests? Does the Cross Origin Request block all javascript or just client side javascript?

Comment: If the api doesn't allow CORS, then no matter how you access it, it will fail if you are not on their server. What API are you using, and why does it not allow CORS?

Comment: @ribsies I am using the destiny game api. Located here. https://www.bungie.net/en/Clan/Post/39966/85087279/0/0

Comment: A *browser environment* enforces the *same-origin policy*, which prevents scripts from reading cross-origin resources. It does not matter what scripting language is used in the browser environment (though it is traditionally JavaScript). If your resource-fetching script does not run inside of a browser, it is not subject to the same-origin policy. (CORS headers from a server tells the browser environment to relax the same-origin policy for a particular resource.)

Comment: @ribsies no, that's not true if the requests are made from a server-side proxy.  CORS is about telling a **browser** that a cross-origin request is OK.

Comment: The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) only applies to code run on the client's machine because the request was historically made as though the user had requested it themselves. Server-side, the code runs isolated from the user, so the SOP and CORS don't apply. You can use [`http.get()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) and [`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) here.